# Async C++ socket

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

I am trying to write an asynchronous server to handle multiple users at the same time. The server is standing in the main thread listening for receiving data, in the same thread it receives them (large images) and creates a task to process this data, which it sends to the thread pool, and itself listens to the next image. Here is the code (Handle contains data processing that is performed on another thread):

```
while (true) {
    cv::Mat data = ReceiveImage();

    m_Pool.AddTask([=]() mutable {
        Handle(std::move(data));
    });
}

cv::Mat UDPServer::ReceiveImage() const {
    ...
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < sz; i += num_bytes) {
            num_bytes = ReceiveData((char*)&buf[0] + i, sz - i, from);
        }
    }
    ...
}

int UDPServer::ReceiveData(char* buf, int len, sockaddr_in& from) const {
    socklen_t slen = sizeof(from);
    int nReceivedBytes = recvfrom(m_Socket, buf, len, 0, (sockaddr*)&from, &slen);

    if (nReceivedBytes == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        throw std::runtime_error(RECEIVEFROM_ERROR.data());
    }

    return nReceivedBytes;
}
```

There is a problem with this approach: while accepting data from one user, another user can send his data, which will not be accepted.

A possible solution is to accept the data on a different thread. To do this, I want to receive ONLY a signal in the main thread that data has arrived, and transfer them to another thread to receive and send them to the thread pool. Something like Probe in MPI.

How can this be implemented on C ++ sockets? I tried to find it on the internet, but nothing came of it. Or does anyone have a better solution to the problem?

Comment: you could take a look at boost asio or Qt::network, both do it

Comment: Your problem is with the loop at `ReceiveImage` - while looping, you are blocking the thread. The correct way would be to place partial data into a buffer and cycle among different clients using a polling function (`poll`, `select`, `epoll`, `kqueue`, etc').

Comment: Another problem is that you're using UDP sockets for streamed data without any data-loss protection. TCP would be a better choice unless you go hardcore and write your own packet loss detection and logic.

Comment: Yeah, i know that, but my task is to write it in C++ socket

Comment: @Egor - everything I wrote about is for C++. System calls (i.e., `poll`) are available in C++. Using TCP/IP instead of UDP is available in C++, dynamic and static sized buffers are available in C++...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Myst. I'm using UDP for better perfomance. 
I heard about `select`, but I think it will give performance drawdowns.

Comment: TCP has hardware optimization support on the network cards. I would recommend to avoid UDP unless each message is less than 1200 bytes long and both message loss and reordering is acceptable. This is why UDP is faster, it has no in-order delivery guaranty. UDP packets may arrive out of order, arrive more than once or never arrive at all. P.S., `poll` is often better then `select`. With more than 1000 clients, **never** use `select`. `epoll` and `kqueue` are both considered faster, but it actually depends on how you use them and how active your sockets get.

Comment: @Myst
Yes you are right. In my task, the order of requests is also important, so I will switch to TCP, especially if there is optimization. As for `select` / `poll` I read, select is used in cases up to 1024 clients. There is also `epoll`, which is newer than its counterparts. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP sockets work this way. There is a listened-to socket, call it P, and an actual communication socket, call it Q. The `accept` system call does this:

```
Q = accept(P, ...); // there are other parameters 
                    // which are not important here
```

As soon as `accept` returns, you can launch an async task on Q, and continue listening on P. The two jobs will not interfere with each other. If another request comes why you are still grinding away on Q, `accept` will just return another Q for another async task.

This whole idea doesn't work all that well for UDP because there are no persistent connections. Each packet is a communication session of its own. It doesn't make a lot of sense to asynchronously read a packet from a socket. Reading is an atomic operation, and packets are short enough. You can launch an asynchronous task to process each packet's data, there's nothing wrong with that. You can try to implement asynchronous reading by `poll`ing on a socket and launching an async task that reads the data as soon as it's ready, but this won't really simplify or speed up anything.

Comment: But what to do in UDP, where a persistent connection is not established using `accept`?

Comment: @Egor Good luck writing something like ReceiveImage in UDP. You will end up re-implementing TCP, poorly. Why would you ever want that? UDP works best for short messages that fit in a packet.

Comment: 'pronouns' m Thanks for help. I'll look at TCP

Comment: @'pronouns' m 
Thanks, I finally understand what you mean. It sounds logical, I will try!